# Websphere: Configuring shared library using deployment descriptors

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have a ear file and it references few jar files at runtime. We created a shared library using websphere admin console. But for referencing the shared library we are looking for a way to configure the shared library using deployment descriptors. Any help on how to do it, which deployment descriptor file to modify to specify the shared lib?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is by using the websphere-specific **deployment.xml** descriptor inside EARs META-INF.

You should put that file inside the following dir tree *META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp/deployment.xml*, then locate the classloader section and set the shared library inside classloader tag as follows:

```
<classloader xmi:id="Classloader_1454339476980" mode="PARENT_FIRST">
 <libraries libraryName="myshared lib" sharedClassloader="true"/>
</classloader>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest is to use [Installed Optional Packages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ccws_installoptpkg.html).